# MySQL selecting multi ids values in one row

Tags: mysql, select, set, multi-select

Here is query:

```
SELECT 
     t1.id, t1.data, t1.invoice_nr, t3.tiekejas, t4.uzsakovas, t1.pard_suma, t1.pirk_suma,
     t1.transporto_suma, t2.apm_id, t2.apm_data, t2.apm_suma, t2.tipas, t1.terminas, 
     t5.regionas, t6.imone, t1.masina, t7.vardas, t7.pavarde, t8.vardas, t8.pavarde
FROM 
     irasai t1
     LEFT JOIN apmokejimai t2 ON t1.invoice_nr = t2.apm_invoice_nr
     LEFT JOIN tiekejai t3 ON t1.tiekejas = t3.id
     LEFT JOIN uzsakovai t4 ON t1.pirkejas = t4.id
     LEFT JOIN regionai t5 ON t1.regionas = t5.id
     LEFT JOIN transportas t6 ON t1.transporto_imone = t6.id
     LEFT JOIN vadybininkai t7 ON t1.pard_vad = t7.id
     LEFT JOIN vadybininkai t8 ON t1.pirk_vad = t8.id
GROUP BY t1.invoice_nr, t2.apm_id
ORDER BY t1.data, t1.invoice_nr
```

And the problem is that table t1 some columns(tiekejas, pirkejas, regionas, trasporto_imone, pard_vad, pirk_vad) is sets of ids(ex. 1,2,5 etc). This query returns value only of one id from set, I want to get it all in one row (every value in new line or separated by dot or something, I can split them later in program). For now I split them in program, but I was required to select them one by one from database, and that takes too much time, and programs working too slow then.

I hope there is a better solution for this. Thanks.

HERE IS SQL FIDDLE LINK: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8609/1

EDIT:
http://postimg.org/image/3sostf42n/

This what I need to get, defined column is t1.tiekejas (ex. 1,2,5), this ids have values in table t3 (tiekejai), by this query it only returns one value by id 1, but I need three values of ids 1,2,5 returned.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Added SQL Fiddle link

Comment: Excellent. You score "1", out of a possible "2".

Comment: that you still miss one of the two things that @Strawberry was correctly asking you to provide: what do you want to obtain? But not in words. Show us how the desired table should look like!

Comment: Added picture with wanted result.

Comment: No pictures thanks. Just paste the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial problem can be fixed using FIND_IN_SET:-

```
SELECT 
     t1.id, t1.data, t1.invoice_nr, t3.tiekejas, t4.uzsakovas, t1.pard_suma, t1.pirk_suma,
     t1.transporto_suma, t2.apm_id, t2.apm_data, t2.apm_suma, t2.tipas, t1.terminas, 
     t5.regionas, t6.imone, t1.masina, t7.vardas, t7.pavarde, t8.vardas, t8.pavarde
FROM 
     irasai t1
     LEFT JOIN apmokejimai t2 ON t1.invoice_nr = t2.apm_invoice_nr
     LEFT JOIN tiekejai t3 ON FIND_IN_SET(t3.id, t1.tiekejas)
     LEFT JOIN uzsakovai t4 ON FIND_IN_SET(t4.id, t1.pirkejas)
     LEFT JOIN regionai t5 ON FIND_IN_SET(t5.id, t1.regionas)
     LEFT JOIN transportas t6 ON FIND_IN_SET(t6.id, t1.transporto_imone)
     LEFT JOIN vadybininkai t7 ON FIND_IN_SET(t7.id, t1.pard_vad)
     LEFT JOIN vadybininkai t8 ON FIND_IN_SET(t8.id, t1.pirk_vad)
GROUP BY t1.invoice_nr, t2.apm_id
ORDER BY t1.data, t1.invoice_nr
```

However I think you are going to have issues with the multiple values from each joined table. Further you are using GROUP BY to eliminate the multiple rows, and which one of the various values for each column for a particular invoice_nr / apm_id that is chosen is not defined.

Note, also it is generally a bad idea to have a field containing a comma separated list of ids. It makes doing a join slow and harder than it should be (as indexes cannot effectively be used on the field), and it limits future increases in the data. It is generally a sign of a poorly normalised database design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need this ids in one column, because invoices can have more then one customer, transport etc. I think best solution is to write stored procedures which gets string, then splits it, select each value, and returning them in string

Comment: You can split the ids off into a different table, with (say) one row per customer on each invoice (this is what is normally done). FIND_IN_SET does work, and is FAR faster than a stored procedure will be but is still FAR slower than just having a properly indexed join on a pair of integers.

Comment: Can you show me and example of your advice? I do not really understand how it can be done, thanks.

Comment: I have done a quick mod to one of the joins (against tiekejai ) to give you an example here - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c1ea/2 . But difficult to demonstrate it fully as the GROUP BY clause you have in the query will hide most of the values